# Is my DRF create function losing data before saving?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following DRF viewset:

```
class RecordViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer
    filterset_fields = ['task', 'workday']
    
    def get_workday(self, request):
        date = get_date_from_calendar_string(request.data['date'])
        obj, _ = Workday.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, date=date)
        return obj.id
    
    def create(self, request):
        request.data['workday'] = self.get_workday(request)
        print(request.data)
        return super().create(request)
```

The `create()` method is failing on a not-null constraint:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "task_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (159, Added via task panel., 0, 0, 0, null, t, f, null, 98).
```

However, the print statement in `create()` shows that the data present in the submission:

`{'minutes_planned': 5, 'description': 'Added via task panel.', 'minutes_worked': 5, 'task': 148, 'workday': 98}`

I am not seeing the pk for `task` (148) in the error statement for some reason, indicating to me that it is getting dropped somewhere. I am not using any signals, or overriding `save()` in the model. What else could be causing this problem? I've just started using DRF, so it might be something obvious.

=====

This is the model:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='records')
    workday = models.ForeignKey(Workday, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='records')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    minutes_planned = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minutes_worked = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minutes_worked_store = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_generated = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and the serializer:

```
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = TaskSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Record
        fields = ['id', 'workday', 'description', 'completed', 'task', 'minutes_worked', 'minutes_planned']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TaskSerializer` is `read_only` for the `RecordSerializer` which does not allow writing that field and therefor will be ignored on `create`.

Change your code to the following should work

```py
class RecordSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    task = TaskSerializer(read_only=True)
    task_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=models.Task.objects.all(), write_only=True)
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Comment: replace that line with `task = TaskSerializer(queryset=models.Task.objects.all())`

Comment: Ah, thank you. That makes sense. Unfortunately, without `read_only`, it won't accept an integer for the task field at all. (Expects a dictionary). I've simply removed the entire line for now.

Comment: You could split the field into a serialized field for reading and a related primary key field just for writing. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide the code of the TaskSerializer, it's hard to say what happens there under the hood.

It looks to me that you are trying to assign somewhere `task=148` instead of `task_id=148`. Normally the model expects that the task field will be and instance of class `Task`, while `task_id` can be the `pk` of this instance.